# jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

In the following code, the click event is added explicitly to the body, so that even if click outside the button say on the body the div with ID tip1 should close with a fade effect. 
The problem here is that the the div closes even if we click on the div itself. 
Any idea on this would help ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').getit({speed: 150, delay: 300});
    });

    $.fn.getit = function(options){


    var defaults = {
        speed: 200,
        delay: 300
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    $(this).each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var tip = $('.tip');
        this.title = "";
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var tLeft = offset.left;
        var tTop = offset.top;
        var tWidth = $this.width();
        var tHeight = $this.height();


    $this.click(

            function() {

            if($('.tip').hasClass('.active101')) {
                $('.tip').fadeOut("slow");
                $('.tip').removeClass('.active101').addClass('.inactive101');

            }
            else {
                setTip(tTop, tLeft);
                $('body').bind('click',function(e) {
                        var parentElement = "button1";
                        var parentElement2 = "tip1"
                        if( e.target.id != parentElement) {
                            $('.tip').fadeOut("slow");
                            $('.tip').removeClass('.active101').addClass('.inactive101');
                        }

                }); 
                $('.tip').removeClass('.inactive101').addClass('.active101');
                setTimer();
            }
            }, 
            function() {
                if($('.tip').hasClass('.inactive101')) {
                stopTimer();
                tip.hide();
                }
            }
    );  

        setTimer = function() {

            $this.showTipTimer = setInterval("showTip()", defaults.delay);

        }

        stopTimer = function() {
            clearInterval($this.showTipTimer);
        }


        setTip = function(top, left){
            var topOffset = tip.height();
            var xTip = (left-440)+"px";
            var yTip = (top-topOffset+100)+"px";
            tip.css({'top' : yTip, 'left' : xTip});
        }

    showTip = function(){
            stopTimer();

            tip.animate({"top": "+=20px", "opacity": "toggle"}, defaults.speed);
        }   

    });
};
```

```
<div class="main">

        <a href="#" class="button" id="button1">
            Click Me!
        </a>
        <div class="tip" id="tip1">Hello again</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use the jQuery unbind function (http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) on the div.  Just move the click event details into a named function, and then call unbind on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Set the click event on your div to 'stopPropagation'

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can bind a click event to the div itself and prevent the click event from bubbling up?

```
$("#div").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Rick.

Comment: I think he wants clicks on the body to close the div, but clicks on the div to keep it open - this is the opposite of that.

Comment: @idbentley - From what I can read he wants the div to remain open if he clicks on it - "The problem here is that the the div closes even if we click on the div itself.".

Answer (score 0):

1. you should stop the event's propagation
2. you should check if any of the element's children are clicked (if you click a child of that element, the element would close)
3. you should probably be more careful with your selectors(if you intend to use this only on one element - because you are verifying with an id ('#button1' which is unique), you shouldn't bind the getit function to all the elements with class '.button')

   ```
   if( e.target.id != parentElement 
      && $(e.target).parents('#'+parentElement).length == 0) {
       $('.tip').fadeOut("slow");
       $('.tip').removeClass('.active101').addClass('.inactive101');
       e.stopPropagation();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. Tried with all of them and each worked. But I also found another solution to this by just adding another condition:

```
if (e.target.id != parentElement && e.target.id != parentElement2) {
    $('.tip').fadeOut("slow");
    $('.tip').removeClass('.active101').addClass('.inactive101');
}
```